# NIFI custom processor return multipleflow files in recursion

Tags: java, apache-nifi

I have to do some custom preprocessing tasks on a huge data file (~200GB).
currently, its works as below way.

1. select * from table
2. preprocessing line by line
3. return a new single flow file

so I decided to convert the above approach to the below way.

1. get the row count from the user (let's assume the user gives 1000)
2. execute select * query as resultSet
3. read the results line by line (rs.next())
4. when the line count reaches 1000 return the flow file and continues to other lines

So my approach is as below
**onTrigger**

```
 public void onTrigger(final ProcessContext context, final ProcessSession session) throws ProcessException {
        logger = getLogger();
        FlowFile flowFile = session.get();
        if (flowFile == null) {
            return;
        }
        try {
            final Long rowLimit = context.getProperty(ProcessorUtils.MAX_RECORD).evaluateAttributeExpressions(flowFile).asLong(); 
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    // db connection properties
            );
            Statement stm = conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
            ResultSet rs = stm.executeQuery("sql query");
            Map<String, String> flowFileAttributes = flowFile.getAttributes();
            process(
                    rs,
                    session,
                    flowFileAttributes,
                    rowLimit,
            );
    
            FlowFile stateFlowFile = session.create();
            session.putAttribute(stateFlowFile, "processing_status", "end");
            session.putAttribute(stateFlowFile, "record_count", "0");
            session.transfer(stateFlowFile, GPReaderProcessorUtils.STATUS); // working line

        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.warn(" conn " + e);
            session.transfer(flowFile, GPReaderProcessorUtils.FAILURE);
        }
    }
```

**Recursion Approach for termination based on line count**

```
        private void process(ResultSet rs, ProcessSession session, Map<String, String> flowFileAttributes, Long rowLimit) throws SQLException {
           try{
                logger.info("->  start processing with row limit = " + rowLimit);
                AtomicInteger mainI = new AtomicInteger(0);
                FlowFile flowFile = 
                session.write(session.putAllAttributes(session.create(), flowFileAttributes), (OutputStream out) -> {
                int i = 0;
                Map<String, String> preProcessResults = null;
                try {
                     String res = "";
                     while (i < rowLimit && rs.next()) {
                           //preprocessing happens here
                            i++;
                            mainI.set(i);
                            out.write(preprocess results.toString().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
                       }
                    }catch (SQLException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                logger.info("gp-log ->"+ (String.valueOf(i)));
                out.close();
            });


            FlowFile stateFlowFile = session.create();
            session.putAttribute(stateFlowFile, "processing_status", "processing");
            session.putAttribute(stateFlowFile, "record_count", mainI.toString());
            session.transfer(stateFlowFile, GPReaderProcessorUtils.STATUS); // state relationship


            session.transfer(flowFile, GPReaderProcessorUtils.SUCCESS); // preprocessed flow files returns

            if(!rs.isAfterLast() && mainI != 0  && !rs.isLast()){ // recurrsion call
                logger.info("gp-log -> recursion call" );
                process(rs, session,flowFileAttributes,column,rowLimit);
            }

        }catch (Exception e){
            logger.info(e.getMessage());
            logger.error(e.getMessage());
      session.transfer(session.putAllAttributes(session.create(),flowFileAttributes), GPReaderProcessorUtils.FAILURE);
        }


    }
```

Expected Behaviour -> while processing this one return completed rows as flow files

Current Behaviour -> after finishing all return all flow files (generated in recursion) once.

please advise on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your processor should extend [AbstractSessionFactoryProcessor](https://github.com/apache/nifi/blob/main/nifi-api/src/main/java/org/apache/nifi/processor/AbstractSessionFactoryProcessor.java) and create/commit sessions for incoming file and for each outgoing file.

files going to output queue as soon as session been committed.

Comment: #daggett it's working correctly in my local env, but I deployed it in a 4-node cluster and now when this processor is running, the node suddenly goes out of the cluster with the below warnings.


`xxx.xx.xx:xxxx- warning - Response time from yyy.yy.yy:yyyy was slow for each last 3 requests made.
xxx.xx.xx:xxxx- warning - Response time from yyy.yy.yy:yyyy was slow for each last 3 requests made.
xxx.xx.xx:xxxx- warning - Response time from yyy.yy.yy:yyyy was slow for each last 3 requests made.`

x is the master node and y is the node with which the processor runs.

Comment: how many files you are producing? what is the limit of output queue? think about grouping flowfiles - for example commit by 10... how many threads you have configured in nifi?

Comment: before it generates result files (~200GB) it goes out of the cluster. thread properties as below

`[abc@server conf]$ cat nifi.properties | grep thread
nifi.swap.in.threads=4
nifi.swap.out.threads=4
nifi.provenance.repository.query.threads=16
nifi.provenance.repository.index.threads=16
nifi.provenance.repository.concurrent.merge.threads=4
nifi.web.jetty.threads=400
nifi.cluster.node.protocol.threads=10
nifi.cluster.node.protocol.max.threads=60
nifi.cluster.load.balance.max.thread.count=60
`
it would be grate if you can share some guides for grouping flowfile scenario